# Wordpress + Laravel - Setup

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel, routes

I'm  developing a system in **Laravel** to handle a lot of customer related data, all the data should be saved to the database I setup with **Laravel**.

My question is?

If I want to use **Wordpress** as the **frontend page**, but keep Laravel in the background to handle all data from our customers. 
And the user comes to **mydomain.com(Wordpress frontend)**, and a showed a formula that the customer should fill out. 
When they push **submit** i would like to save this data in the **laravel** database **not the Wordpress database**.

How should I go around this, what is the **best setup**?

Idea I have for setup

**Call to save in database from Wordpress**
-- app.mydomain.com/save/to/database -- Is This a bad call to make?

**Domain setup**
**Laravel** = app.mydomain.com
**Wordpress** = mydomain.com

Anybody have some input :)

**Thanks
/d**

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a custom function that collects your form data from the Wordpress page. Which route you go to do this is up to you. You could roll your own, extend a plugin, etc.
2. [Using a custom connection to your Laravel project's db](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database), store the code.